# css- group same classes together and wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

I have the following div+select elements that I would like to place next to each other. Once the end of html width is reached, the following elements should be wrapped to next row.
Please note all div's are having same className and are dynamic in number. Can someone help how this can be achieved with CSS/reactjs/jquery. Thanks in advance!

```
<div className="filterContainer">
    <div className="filterChildDiv">
        <label className="filterHeader">Status</label>
        <Select className="select-teams" />
    </div>

    <div className="filterChildDiv">
        <label className="filterHeader">Status</label>
        <Select className="select-teams" />
    </div>
</div> 
    ...
```

CSS:

```
.filterChildDiv{
    flex: 1;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.filterContainer{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking like this?

```js
    setInterval(() => {
      document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].innerHTML += `<div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>`;
    }, 500);
```

```css
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .filterChildDiv {
      display: flex;
      flex: 1;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
    .filterChildDiv *{
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>
    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>
    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>
    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>
    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>
    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>
    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>    <div class="filterChildDiv">
      <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
      <Select class="select-teams" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
        <select class="select-teams" >
          <option>choose something</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
        <select class="select-teams" >
         <option>choose something</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
        <select class="select-teams" >
         <option>choose something</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
        <select class="select-teams" >
         <option>choose something</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label class="filterHeader">Status</label>
        <select class="select-teams" >
         <option>choose something</option>
        </select>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```